# Как сделать обновление for'a медленее

Tags: c#

Пытался и так, и сяк, в итоге получается мелькающая билиберда

```
void space(int num)
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            }
            int bitok;
            bitok = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (bitok == 1)
            {
                float mine = 0f;
                string videocard = "GTX 480";
                for (; ; )
                {
                    space(10);//моя функция для пробелов(10 - колво пробелов)
                    print("1.Сколько намайнено(Обновить)");
                    print("Прокачать(1000)");
                    print("Текущая видеокарта: " + videocard);
                    mine += 0.01f;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант  использовать  [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Перед использованием следует подключить: `using System.Threading`

```
using System.Threading;
//...
int sleepTimeInMilliSeconds = 1000;
Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeInMilliSeconds);
```

> Приостанавливает текущий поток на заданное количество миллисекунд.